# ios use pjsip no sound

Tags: ios, pjsip

i use pod 'pjsip' integrate

Microphone permission granted

Configured PJ_AUTOCONF=1

Registering, logging in, dialing and getting connected are all successful

There is no error message in the xcode console

When I dial h5 (h5 uses webrtc), I can’t hear his voice, and he can’t hear mine either.

Normal calls can be made between h5

My iPhone microphone icon is also on

Please tell me what may be the problem,thanks